# Can you start conditional tasks inside an async gulp task?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I want to create a task that only builds the entire project if something changed. For that, I am comparing hashes (irrelevant to the question).

```js
const buildIfChanged = async () => {
  const hash = await getHash();
  const newHash = await getNewHash();

  if (hash !== newHash) {
    console.log("START");
    const task = series(build, cleanup)();
    console.log("END", task);
  }
};
```

In this example, `task` is `undefined`, so I cannot add a `.on("end", ...)` and resolve the promise after that. I also cannot await it.

The problem is, because I am not waiting for it to complete, the `buildIfChanged` task completes before `build` even has a chance to run.

Is there any way to do this with modern gulpfiles?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution on how to do this in modern gulpfiles. The function call of `parallel` and `series` actually take a done function as a parameter.

So to solve this, you can do:

```js
const buildIfChanged = async () => {
  return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
    try {
      const hash = await getHash();
      const newHash = await getNewHash();

      if (hash !== newHash) {
        console.log("START");
        const task = series(build, cleanup)(() => res()); // add the done function here
        console.log("END", task);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      rej(e);
    }
  })
};
```